# Indent wrapped text GT

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra, gt

I am attempting to indent text in the stub for a GT table. Some of the text in the stub is quite long and wraps across multiple lines. When I apply an indentation to the stub, the second (and subsequent) lines of the text are not indented. I simply want to indent the entire wrapped text of the stub.

Here is a reproducible example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(gt)
library(tidyr)
# Get vectors of 2-letter country codes for
# each region of Oceania
Australasia <- c("AU", "NZ")
Melanesia <- c("NC", "PG", "SB", "VU")
Micronesia <- c("FM", "GU", "KI", "MH", "MP", "NR", "PW")
Polynesia <- c("PF", "WS", "TO", "TV")

# Create a gt table based on a preprocessed `countrypops`
countrypops %>%
  filter(country_code_2 %in% c(
    Australasia, Melanesia, Micronesia, Polynesia)
  ) %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1995, 2005, 2015)) %>%
  mutate(region = case_when(
    country_code_2 %in% Australasia ~ "Australasia",
    country_code_2 %in% Melanesia ~ "Melanesia",
    country_code_2 %in% Micronesia ~ "Micronesia",
    country_code_2 %in% Polynesia ~ "Polynesia",
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = population) %>%
  arrange(region, desc(`2015`)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("country_code")) %>%
  gt(
    rowname_col = "country_name",
    groupname_col = "region"
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = list(
      cell_text(indent = pct(8))
    ),
    locations = cells_stub()
  ) %>% 
  cols_width(country_name ~ 150)
```

Picture of incorrectly indented table:
[image: Picture of incorrectly indented table]

How can I apply indenting consistently across the stub rows?

Answer (score 1):

Intend (`text-indent`) only applies to the first line, for multiple lines use `padding-left`, e.g.

```
countrypops %>%
  filter(country_code_2 %in% c(
    Australasia, Melanesia, Micronesia, Polynesia)
  ) %>%
  filter(year %in% c(1995, 2005, 2015)) %>%
  mutate(region = case_when(
    country_code_2 %in% Australasia ~ "Australasia",
    country_code_2 %in% Melanesia ~ "Melanesia",
    country_code_2 %in% Micronesia ~ "Micronesia",
    country_code_2 %in% Polynesia ~ "Polynesia",
  )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = population) %>%
  arrange(region, desc(`2015`)) %>%
  select(-starts_with("country_code")) %>%
  gt(
    rowname_col = "country_name",
    groupname_col = "region"
  ) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = "padding-left:30px;",
    locations = cells_stub()
  ) %>%
  cols_width(country_name ~ 150)
```

[image]